# C code doesn't work, but no errors shown

Tags: c, string, logic, ctype

I am preparing for my Computer Science practical examination, when I hit this roadblock.
The following C code is to capitalize all the words in a string taken from the user.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char a[20];
    int i;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",a);

    if(islower(a[0])!=0)
    {
        a[0]=toupper(a[0]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
        if(a[i]==' ' && isalpha(a[i+1]!=0))
            a[i+1]=toupper(a[i+1]);

    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

But the above code doesn't perform the task. It takes the input, but gives the same output(the entered string, as is). Also, there are no errors or warnings shown. I am coding in Ubuntu 14.04 using gcc. I don't seem to understand as to why the code doesn't work.

Comment: learn to use a debugger (gdb in this case)

Comment: Due to the fact that `toupper` will return the passed-in value if there is no upper-case equivalence, this code can be considerably simpler. And if you want extended-ascii to work as well, you should consider a cast to `unsigned char` within call to `toupper`. and **Please don't change the posted code in response to answers given.** The change you just made, `if(islower(a[0])!=0)` just made Pat's answer meaningless in the context of the code posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is with `isalpha(a[i+1]!=0)`, as you should simply check `isalpha(a[i+1])`. The return-value of the expression `a[i+1]!=0` is 1 for all the characters in the input string, except for the last one. The return-value of `isalpha(1)` is 0, and so the statement under the `if` condition will execute **only** for the last character, and **only** if that character is preceded by a space character.

Having said that, here is a better way for you to implement the whole thing:

```
for (i=1; a[i]!=0; i++)
    if (a[i-1]==' ' && isalpha(a[i]))
        a[i] = toupper(a[i]);
```

Comment: @Neil: Did you try the first suggestion or the extended suggestion?

Comment: I had earlier tried the first answer, but the extended one works correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @Neil: You're welcome :) please see the updated answer which includes an explanation to your original problem.

Answer (score 2):

Should your block :

```
if(islower(a[0])==0)
{
   a[0]=toupper(a[0]);
}
```

be checking that it is not equal to zero rather than it is?

Comment: This block checks whether the first letter of the string is small, and if true, converts it to capital.

Comment: Yes, but islower(a[0]) returns 0 if the letter is not lowercase.  I read this as : if upper case -> convert to upper case.  I think you need a != 0 rather than a == 0

Answer (score 0):

check the first ) in  isalpha(a[i+1]!=0)),its misplaced.

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    if(a[i]==' ' && isalpha(a[i+1])!=0)
        a[i+1]=toupper(a[i+1]);
```

also the first if should be

```
if(islower(a[0]){}
```

Comment: Exactly. These were the changes required. Thanks @halfdreamer.